# Api-Platform IriConverter Symfony context

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

My service (a console command) is receiving the IRI strings as arguments (I have this requirement, instead using the ids, that would be way more simple). So I have injected the ApiPlatform's IriConverter to my service, but when I call its getItemFromIri method I'm getting this error:

> The token storage contains no authentication token. One possible reason may be that there is no firewall configured for this URL.

My Service:

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Api\IriConverterInterface;
 ....
$context= []; // don't know what to include here
$iri= '/api/v4/files/448';
$file = $this->iriConverter->getItemFromIri($iri, $context);
```

My security.yml

```
firewalls:
    apiV4:
        pattern: ^/api/v4
        stateless: true
        fos_oauth:  true
```

My Class

```
/**
 * File
 * @ApiResource(
 *     attributes={
 *     "normalization_context"={"groups"={"fileUpload"}}
 *     },
 *      collectionOperations = {
 *          "get",
 *          "post" ={
 *              "method"="POST",
 *              "path"="/files",
 *              "controller"= UploadFileAction::class,
 *              "defaults"={"_api_receive"=false},
 *              }
 *          }
 * )
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="UploadedFile")
 * 
*/
class File
{
/**
 * @var int
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * @Groups({"fileUpload"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 * @Groups({"fileUpload"})
 */
private $name;
....
```